# Parsing Binary expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, binary-tree

I have an expression like this:

```
{
  "type": "BinaryExpression",
  "operator": "OR",
  "left": {
    "type": "Literal",
    "value": 1,
    "raw": "1"
  },
  "right": {
    "type": "BinaryExpression",
    "operator": "AND",
    "left": {
      "type": "Literal",
      "value": 2,
      "raw": "2"
    },
    "right": {
      "type": "Literal",
      "value": 3,
      "raw": "3"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to convert this into the following in JS.

```
logic: 'OR'
filters: [
    {1}
    logic: 'AND'
    filters: [
        {2},
        {3}

    ]
]
```

i.e. When there is an operator, I will put into a  logic variable of the Javascript object. After that, I will check if there is a left and right attribute. If any of them is a literal, I will just add to filters array of javascript object. If the left and the right attribute is a binary expression, then inside the javascript object I would repeat the above process.

I tried various approaches, but somehow I would miss something. So, I am asking here. :

```
var currentFilter = {
  'logic': null,
  filters: []
};
test(expression, currentFilter);

function test(expression, currentFilter) {
  while (expression.left != null && expression.right != null) {
    currentFilter.logic = expression.operator;
    if (expression.left.type === 'Literal') {
      currentFilter.filters.push = expression.left.value;
    } else if (expression.left.type === 'BinaryExpression') {
      test(expression.left, currentFilter);
    }

    if (expression.right.type === 'Literal') {
      currentFilter.filters.push = expression.right.value;
    } else if (expression.right.type === 'BinaryExpression') {
      test(expression.right, currentFilter);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The example ("the following in JS") is not valid javascript. Could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: The expression is a JSON.stringify(expression) output. Initially, the whole expression will be a binary expression. In the whole expression, I put 'operator ' in currentFilter.logic variable. After that, In the expression, If the left attribute is Literal, I want to put it into currentFilter.filters array. If it is not a literal but a BinaryExpression, then I create an object of type currentFilter inside currentFilter.filters[] array as this array can hold elements of different type. Then I again check the operator and put it in currentFilter.filters['logic'] and keep on nesting.

Comment: Same for currentFilter.right

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are pretty close with your example, and are trying to use recursion to build your desired object. The reason why yours is failing is likely the `while` loop, as it will get into an infinite loop due to `expression` not being updated. Something like this should be more like what you are looking for:

```js
const exp = {
  "type": "BinaryExpression",
  "operator": "OR",
  "left": {
    "type": "Literal",
    "value": 1,
    "raw": "1"
  },
  "right": {
    "type": "BinaryExpression",
    "operator": "AND",
    "left": {
      "type": "Literal",
      "value": 2,
      "raw": "2"
    },
    "right": {
      "type": "Literal",
      "value": 3,
      "raw": "3"
    }
  }
}

const parseValue = v => v.type === 'Literal' ? v.value : parseExp(v)

const parseExp = ({ operator, left, right }) => ({
  logic: operator,
  filters: [parseValue(left), parseValue(right)]
})

console.log(parseExp(exp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a recursive approach -

```
const eval = (expr) =>
{ switch (expr.type)
  { case 'Literal':
      return expr.value
    case 'BinaryExpression':
      return apply
        ( expr.operator
        , eval (expr.left)
        , eval (expr.right)
        )
    default:
      throw Error (`invalid expression type: ${type}`)
  }
}

const apply = (op, l, r) =>
{ switch (op)
  { case 'AND':
      return l && r
    case 'OR':
      return l || r
    default:
      throw Error (`invalid operator: ${op}`)
  }
}

console.log(eval(e))
// 1 || (2 && 3)
// => 1
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const eval = (expr) =>
{ switch (expr.type)
  { case 'Literal':
      return expr.value
    case 'BinaryExpression':
      return apply
        ( expr.operator
        , eval (expr.left)
        , eval (expr.right)
        )
    default:
      throw Error (`invalid expression type: ${type}`)
  }
}

const apply = (op, l, r) =>
{ switch (op)
  { case 'AND':
      return l && r
    case 'OR':
      return l || r
    default:
      throw Error (`invalid operator: ${op}`)
  }
}

const e =
  { type: "BinaryExpression"
  , operator: "OR"
  , left:
      { type: "Literal"
      , value: 1
      , raw: "1"
      }
  , right:
      { type: "BinaryExpression"
      , operator: "AND"
      , left:
          { type: "Literal"
          , value: 2
          , raw: "2"
          }
      , right:
          { type: "Literal"
          , value: 3
          , raw: "3"
          }
      }
  }


console.log(eval(e))
// 1 || (2 && 3)
// => 1
```

Now hopefully you can see how to build the result you want. This is left an exercise for the reader.